# how to view orders made by customer in admin panel

Tags: php, html, laravel, e-commerce

I'm making my first e-commerce website but I didn't know how to create and view the orders of customers in the admin panel. I tried to follow different tutorials but it didn't work for me. and as I'm new to laravel I'm not sure where to add the lines.

this is my **OrdersController**

```php
class OrdersController extends Controller
{
    public function index () {
        $session_id = Session::get('session_id');
        $cart_datas = Cart_model::where('session_id', $session_id)->get();
        $total_price = 0;
        foreach ($cart_datas as $cart_data) {
            $total_price += $cart_data->price * $cart_data->quantity;
        }
        $shipping_address = DB::table('delivery_address')->where('users_id', Auth::id())->first();
        return view('checkout.review_order', compact('shipping_address', 'cart_datas', 'total_price'));
    }

    public function order (Request $request) {
        $input_data = $request->all();
        $payment_method = $input_data['payment_method'];
        Orders_model::create($input_data);
        if ( $payment_method == "COD" ) {
            return redirect('/cod');
        } else {
            return redirect('/paypal');
        }
    }

    public function cod () {
        $user_order = Orders_model::where('users_id', Auth::id())->first();
        return view('payment.cod', compact('user_order'));
    }

    public function paypal (Request $request) {
        $who_buying = Orders_model::where('users_id', Auth::id())->first();
        return view('payment.paypal', compact('who_buying'));
    }

    public function show($id) {}
}
```

this is **web.php**

```php
/* Admin Location */
Auth::routes(['register'=>false]);
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>['auth','admin']],function () {
    Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin_home');
    /// Setting Area
    Route::get('/settings', 'AdminController@settings');
    Route::get('/check-pwd', 'AdminController@chkPassword');
    Route::post('/update-pwd', 'AdminController@updatAdminPwd');
    /// Category Area
    Route::resource('/category', 'CategoryController');
    Route::get('delete-category/{id}', 'CategoryController@destroy');
    Route::get('/check_category_name', 'CategoryController@checkCateName');
    /// Products Area
    Route::resource('/product', 'ProductsController');
    Route::get('delete-product/{id}', 'ProductsController@destroy');
    Route::get('delete-image/{id}', 'ProductsController@deleteImage');
    /// Product Attribute
    Route::resource('/product_attr', 'ProductAtrrController');
    Route::get('delete-attribute/{id}', 'ProductAtrrController@deleteAttr');
    /// Product Images Gallery
    Route::resource('/image-gallery', 'ImagesController');
    Route::get('delete-imageGallery/{id}', 'ImagesController@destroy');
    /// ///////// Coupons Area //////////
    Route::resource('/coupon', 'CouponController');
    Route::get('delete-coupon/{id}', 'CouponController@destroy');
    //Admin orders Routes 
    Route::resource('/view-Orders', 'OrdersController@index');
});
```

this is my **adminside bar**

```html
<!--sidebar-menu-->
<div id="sidebar"><a href="{{url('/admin')}}" class="visible-phone"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> Dashboard</a>
    <ul>
        <li{{$menu_active==1? ' class=active':''}}><a href="{{url('/admin')}}"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></a> </li>
        <li class="submenu {{$menu_active==2? ' active':''}}"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-th-list"></i> <span>Categories</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{{url('/admin/category/create')}}">Add New Category</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{route('category.index')}}">List Categories</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu {{$menu_active==3? ' active':''}}"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-th-list"></i> <span>Products</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{{url('/admin/product/create')}}">Add New Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="{{route('product.index')}}">List Products</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="submenu {{$menu_active==3? ' active':''}}"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-th-list"></i> <span>Orders</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="{{url('/admin/view-orders')}}">list orders</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<!--sidebar-menu-->
```

Comment: first of all you are pointing a resource route to a single controller action which is not right. now make sure what do you want. you want to view the admin all the orders made by all the customers??

Comment: You need a full tutorial not an answer on stack overflow

Comment: @zahidhasanemon yes i want the admin to view all orders made by all customers

Comment: @N69S i tried to follow a tutorial but i didn't get it well as i'm new to laravel.

Comment: Well, try another tutorial and add up the knowledge

Answer (score 0):

you should have learn more before starting a big project. this is a simple `read` operation from database. however i am giving you a simple example

admin sidebar

```
<li class="submenu {{$menu_active==3? ' active':''}}">
    <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-th-list"></i> <span>Orders</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="{{route('admin.view-orders')}}">list orders</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

route file

```
Route::get('view-orders', 'OrdersController@listOrders')->name('admin.view-orders');
```

Controller

```
public function listOrders() {
    $orders = Orders_model::all(); //here you can order as you wish
    return view('orders.index',compact('orders'));
}
```

and finally the view file

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sl#</th>
            <th>Attributes</th>
            ............
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($orders as $order)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
            <td>{{ $order->attribute }}</td>
            ......................
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

hope you understand the logic.